# Data logger via modbus hardware solution

Tags: data

I have 3 programable logic controllers and other one which isn't part of my solution but I can access usefull data via modbus. I've setup windows service on a remote server to gather data and store it in a SQL Server.
But the problem is if the Internet fails? So I'm searching for a hardware data logger solution.
I saw a schneider scadapack but I think it doesn't support modbus as client.
Everything I'm seeing is hardware with I/O for digital and analog input/outputs but I have already that in PLCs. What I need now is to gather data from the PLCs via modbus RTU/TCP/UDP. After the service detects connection errors it registers the begin date and end date. After it detects PLCs are reachable again it downloads the usefull data that it missed from the hardware data logger solution.

Which solutions support this?

- Yokogawa MW100
- Schneider scadapack models

Both this are data acquisition systems via I/O and probably not via modbus.
I'm lost. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the easiest solution would be to set up a local SQL server with the same setup you have going now on the remote server. I don't see a "hardware" solution being easier, cheaper, or more reliable.

Also a hardware logger usually means nasty csv files to parse afterward. If price is an issue, you could adapt it to run on a smaller linux server or an RPi with MySQL. Put that sever some place clean and on a UPS and you will be just as robust as any "hardware" based solutions that may exist.

Comment: I know, but RPi is kinda risky because you know if you make a lot of I/O on a SD based technology you "burn" the I/O limit. Like 1milion reads and 1milion writes. I have a RPi and I already bought 3 SD cards because of "I/O errors" after some months of usage.... An industrial PC is very expensive. I'm thinking about it and see if it worth or not. Maybe I can configure a sql server mirror... thank you anyway !

Comment: Try an external usb drive on a powered usb hub. https://www.modmypi.com/blog/how-to-mount-an-external-hard-drive-on-the-raspberry-pi-raspian

Comment: Or try a PiDrive. http://gungho.io/product/pidrive/

Answer (score 0):

Ice got experience with horner apg and mt-1xx/2xx by inventia.pl. Personally I've did data collecting from twido (modbus) on mt-151 (inventia, sdcard). You can did same thing on any horner device.